# Remove Emacs backup files with .gitignore recursively

Tags: git

I've set up a boilerplate .gitignore file in my git repository. When using Emacs it creates backup files. I want to remove these recursively. I've tested added:

```
*~
```

But that only removes the files ending with `~` in the root directory. How can I change it to remove recursively?

Comment: As far as I know that should work recursively. `/*~` works the way you say.

Comment: Do you want to remove these files or to ignore them?

Comment: @phd I want to ignore them only. I will test Hanjoung lees solution.

Comment: Then `*~` in the top-level `.gitignore` should work.